# Optimal producer/consumer thread pattern in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, queue, producer-consumer

I have implemented a producer/consumer pattern using Qt threads. Multiple producer threads generate data that are combined by a consumer. Communication is implemented using signals/slots and queued connections. This works fine as long as the consumer is able to consume the data faster than the producer threads produce the data.

It is hard to make my code scale. Particularly it is easy to increase the number of producers but it is very hard to spawn more than one consumer thread.

Now the problem starts when running the software on a CPU/system that has a lot of cores. In that case I use more threads to produce data. It can sometimes happen (depending from the complexity of data generation) that the consumer is not able to handle the produced data in time. Then the Qt event queue fills rapidly with events and the memory consumption grows extremely.

I can solve this by using blocking queued connections. However this does not allow full CPU load since producers tend to wait unnecessarily for the consumer after each data emission.

In a non-Qt software I would use a queue/mailbox/ring-buffer with a fixed size that makes the producers sleep until the consumer frees space in that container. This mechanism limits memory consumption and allows best possible CPU load.

However I could not find an equivalent solution using Qt classes. The event queue is global and has no size property. Is there a Qt way to solve this optimally? If not, are there STL classes I can use to couple (Q)Threads in my way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should move away from using Qt in this case because while the event handling is quite fast, it has clearly not been designed for HPC workloads targeting many-cores (because of the centralized sequential event queue). So I think you should use a fast *atomic muti-producer/multi-consumer (MPMC) queue*. While you could probably write a Qt event layer on top of that, I am not sure this is a good idea performance-wise. An alternative solution is to use *variable-sized chunks* to reduce the amount of events (with a *feedback loop* between the producers and the consumers). Note that regarding your workload, it might be good to consider to use a *task-based runtime* (known to scale well).

If you are searching for a fast MPMC queue, there is the one of provided by Boost ([boost::lockfree::queue](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html)) which is not very fast, but this is often enough. One of the best I am aware of is [this one](https://github.com/rigtorp/MPMCQueue). It is based on a research paper and used in big games. [This one](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue) is slightly faster on my machine on specific cases and more flexible but you should be very careful when using it as consistency is not always ensured (ie. read the docs). Note that the threading library should not matter in the choice of the queue.

Comment: I guess the boost queue should be enough I will give it a try. I'm still surprised how unstable the Qt solution is. Using the event queue for inter-thread communication is recommended anywhere. But when giving it a closer look, it is obvious that it does not scale at all and even computations with variable complexity can't  always be implemented safely. Strange that Qt doesn't even provide a basic ring buffer or a queue size property. That shouldn't be a big deal. Disappointing for a framework used in embedded systems!